# I can`t get move PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I can't make a function so that during the movement of the picturebox which happens with a while loop.

I executed a script on certain coordinates, I tried to do it using the switch statement, but the function simply does not work

When you run it, nothing happens, as if this line of code does not exist.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace shadowfiend_minigame
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int _first_shadowrazeX = 404, _first_shadowrazeY = 204;
        private int _second_shadowrazeX = 724, _second_shadowrazeY = 204;
        private int _third_shadowrazeX = 1106, _third_shadowrazeY = 204;
        private int zeus_hp = 1000;
        private int shadow_fiend_hp = 2800;
        Point point = new Point(1106, 204);
        Point point2 = new Point(724, 204);
        Point point3 = new Point(404, 204);
        private int speed_zeus, damage_zeus;
        private int shadow_fiend_damage;
        Thread thread = new Thread(ShadowRaze_Click);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(ShadowRaze_Click);
            KeyPreview = true;
        }

        bool CheckedBox()
        {
            bool checked1 = checkBox1.Checked;
            bool checked2 = checkBox2.Checked;
            bool checked3 = checkBox3.Checked;
            if (checked1 == false && checked2 == false && checked3 == false)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        }


        private async void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(Zeus);
            if (CheckedBox() == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Выберите сложность игры!");
            }
            else
            {
                Start.Visible = false;
                checkBox1.Visible = false;
                checkBox2.Visible = false;
                checkBox3.Visible = false;
                thread.Start();
            }
        }

        private async void Zeus()
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(Zeus);
            while (shadow_fiend_hp != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                {
                    var x = _zeus.Location.X;
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => _zeus.Location = new Point(_zeus.Location.X - 20, _zeus.Location.Y)));
                    Thread.Sleep(speed_zeus);
                    switch (_zeus.Location.X)
                    /*
                     * Here it is necessary that when the picturebox reaches a certain point while moving, the function is executed
                     */
                    {
                        case 1106:
                            zeus_hp = zeus_hp - 200;
                            this.Invoke(new Action(() => label4.Text = "zeus_hp: " + zeus_hp));
                            break;
                        case 724:
                            zeus_hp = zeus_hp - 200;
                            this.Invoke(new Action(() => label4.Text = "zeus_hp: " + zeus_hp));
                            break;
                        case 404:
                            zeus_hp = zeus_hp - 200;
                            this.Invoke(new Action(() => label4.Text = "zeus_hp: " + zeus_hp));
                            break;
                    }
                }
                Zeus_Attack(damage_zeus);
                if (shadow_fiend_hp == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You lose");
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => Start.Visible = true)); 
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => checkBox1.Visible = true));
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => checkBox2.Visible = true));
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => checkBox3.Visible = true));
                }
                else if (zeus_hp == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You win");
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => Start.Visible = true));
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => checkBox1.Visible = true));
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => checkBox2.Visible = true));
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => checkBox3.Visible = true));
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => _zeus.Location = new Point(_zeus.Location.X + 20, _zeus.Location.Y)));
                    Thread.Sleep(speed_zeus);
                }
            }
            thread.Join();
            ResetAll();
        }

        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkBox3.Checked = false;
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
            speed_zeus = 30;
            damage_zeus = 200;
        }

        private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
            checkBox2.Checked = false;
            speed_zeus = 10;
            damage_zeus = 400;
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkBox3.Checked = false;
            checkBox2.Checked = false;
            speed_zeus = 50;
            damage_zeus = 100;
        }

        private async void Zeus_Attack(int damage)
        {
            shadow_fiend_hp = shadow_fiend_hp - damage;
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => hp.Text = "HP: " + shadow_fiend_hp));
        }

        private async void ShadowFiend_Attack()
        {
            zeus_hp = zeus_hp - 200;
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => label4.Text = "HP: " + shadow_fiend_hp));

        }

        private void ResetAll() 
            => this.Invoke(new Action(() => hp.Text = "HP: 2800"));
      
        private async void ShadowRaze_Click(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Z:
                    shock.Location = new Point(_first_shadowrazeX, _first_shadowrazeY);
                    shock.Visible = true;
                    this.Update();
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    shock.Visible = false;
                    break;
                case Keys.X:
                    shock.Location = new Point(_second_shadowrazeX, _second_shadowrazeY);
                    shock.Visible = true;
                    this.Update();
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    shock.Visible = false;
                    break;
                case Keys.C:
                    shock.Location = new Point(_third_shadowrazeX, _third_shadowrazeY);
                    shock.Visible = true;
                    this.Update();
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    shock.Visible = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: Things that come to mind: you are accessing `shadow_fiend_hp` from a different thread with any interlocking. You should use functions like `Interlocked.Read` and `Interlocked.Add`. Also, why use threads anyway, why not just use `async` `await`?

Comment: That's a lot of code to wade through. First guess though is that the case statement isn't working because `_zeus.Location.X` is never exactly 1106, 724 or 404. If it starts at 1200 then moves by 20 each time then it will never equal those numbers, for instance.

Comment: Okay thanks about streams, I can't implement through them via async and await because I get the error "Waiting for void is not possible"

Comment: There's no point in starting a Thread here (none). It should be clear from that fact that you then need to constantly `Invoke()`, which is synchronous and renders the Thread useless. If you just need to add *pauses*, then yes, you can clearly use async/await.

Comment: @svevlout: it's been a year. Was my answer of any use to you? An upvote and/or an _Accept_ checkmark might be nice next to it

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pretty simple code to move a picture box around the screen using `async` and `await`.  It's not based on your code - yours is far from being a Minimal Reproduceable Example.  This is.

I dropped a few coptrols my form:

- A combo box
- Two textboxes (Offset and Period)
- Two Buttons (Go and Stop)
- A PictureBox (I made this public and gave it an obvious background color

Then I created this `enum` to state the direction I wanted to move the picture box:

```
public enum Direction
{
    SouthEast,
    East,
    NorthEast,
    North,
    NorthWest,
    West,
    SouthWest,
    South,
}
```

Then I created this worker class:

```
internal class PictureBoxMover
{
    public bool enabled = true;
    Direction _direction;
    int _offset;
    int _period;
    Form1 _theForm;

    private static Dictionary<Direction, (int deltaX, int deltaY)> _deltaRules = new Dictionary<Direction, (int deltaX, int deltaY)> {
        { Direction.North, (0, -1) },
        { Direction.South, (0, 1) },
        { Direction.East, (1, 0) },
        { Direction.West, (-1, 0) },
        { Direction.NorthEast, (1, -1) },
        { Direction.NorthWest, (-1, -1) },
        { Direction.SouthEast, (1, 1) },
        { Direction.SouthWest, (-1, 1) },
    };

    public PictureBoxMover (Form1 parentForm, Direction direction, int offset, int period)
    {
        _theForm = parentForm;
        _direction=direction;
        _offset=offset;
        _period=period;
    }

    public void Disable()
    {
        enabled = false;
    }

    public async Task Run()
    {
        var directionRule = _deltaRules[_direction];
        var offsetXY = (directionRule.deltaX * _offset, directionRule.deltaY * _offset);
        while (enabled)
        {
            _theForm.pictureBox1.Location = new Point(_theForm.pictureBox1.Location.X + offsetXY.Item1, _theForm.pictureBox1.Location.Y + offsetXY.Item2);
            await Task.Delay(_period);
        }
    }
}
```

The static `_deltaRules` dictionary makes sense of the `Directions`.  The `( 1, -1 )` denotes a *tuple* of two integers (i.e., `_deltaRules` is a dictionary with a `Direction` as *key* and a two integer tuple as *value*

The main reason for instance of this class is to allow them to be easily cancellable (/disablable).

In the form's constructor, I bind the Direction dropdown combobox to the possible values of Direction:

```
DirectionDropDown.DataSource = Enum.GetNames<Direction>();
```

The rest of the form's class looks like this:

```
private PictureBoxMover? _currentPictureBoxMover = null;

private async void GoBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Enum.TryParse<Direction>(DirectionDropDown.SelectedItem.ToString(), out var direction) &&
        int.TryParse(OffsetTxt.Text, out var offset) &&
        int.TryParse(PeriodTxt.Text, out var period))
    {
        if (_currentPictureBoxMover != null)
        {
            _currentPictureBoxMover.Disable();
        }
        _currentPictureBoxMover = new PictureBoxMover(this, direction, offset, period);
        await _currentPictureBoxMover.Run();
    }
}

private void StopBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_currentPictureBoxMover != null)
    {
        _currentPictureBoxMover.Disable();
    }
    _currentPictureBoxMover = null;
}
```

I keep track of the `_currentPictureBoxMover` so that I can disable it when I start moving in a new direction.  Otherwise the code is pretty self-explanatory.

Note that because everything is done with `async` and `await`, I have no threading issues, and no timers to worry about.

One thing to note: part of the reason for having the period/offset controls is to show (and prove to myself) that the form is fully functional while things are moving around